# How to validate input field to accept the values that are in the array in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, regex

I have a scenario in which the in the input fields should accept values that are present in the array. It should throw error if other values are added.

**.component.html**

```
<input type="text" ([ngModel])="InputValues" (blur)="validate()">
```

**.component.ts**

```
arrayList =  ['table_1', 'table_2', 'table_3', 'table_4'];
```

The arrayList has 4 element, the input field should accept only this values if any other values entered it should throw error. The input should accept values that are present in the arrayList.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash library by installing from angular cli = (npm install lodash)

```
validate() {
    let dataPresentOrNot = lodash.includes(this.arrayList,this.InputValues);
    if (dataPresentOrNot) {
       console.log("Entered Value is in Array List"); // success message
    } else {
       console.log("Entered Value is not in Array List"); // Or any error message 
       document. getElementById('you need to pass id of input element here'). value = '' // you can clear out the text box entered value
    }
  }
```

you can pass in the message using toastr notification for good ui visibility or you can also use Angular Validators method to perform validation.

Answer (score 1):

```js
validate() {
  this.displayMessage = '';
  const arrayList = ['table_1', 'table_2', 'table_3', 'table_4'];
  if (arrayList.indexOf(this.InputValues) > 0) {
    this.displayMessage = "Entered Value is in the Array List";
  } else {
    this.displayMessage = "Entered Value is not in the Array List";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" ([ngModel])="InputValues" (blur)="validate()">
<span *ngIf='displayMessage'></span>
```

Note:- You can check that array contains value by using core javascript. [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method.

Answer (score 0):

We can add custom validators to reactive forms

**in HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="tableForm">
    <div class='form-group'>
        Table values<input id="tableValue" class='form-control' type="text" formControlName="tableValue" required><br>
    </div>
    <span style="color:red" *ngIf="tableForm.get('tableValue').errors?.inputValidator">Enter a valid value</span><br>
</form>
```

**in ts**

```
  title = "TableValues";
  tableForm: FormGroup;


  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Basic FormControl
    this.tableForm = new FormGroup({
      tableValue: new FormControl(),
    });

    // FormBuilder example
    this.tableForm = this.fb.group({
      tableValue: [null, this.inputValidator(['x', 'y', 'z'])],
    });
  }


  inputValidator(val) {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
      if (
        control.value !== null && !val.includes(control.value)
      ) {
        return { inputValidator: true };
      }
      return null;
    };
  }
```